# c: socketCAN connection: read() not fast enough

Tags: performance, database-connection, database-performance, socketcan

socketCAN connection: read() not fast enough

Hello,

I use the socket() connection for my CAN communication.

```
fd = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);
```

I'm using 2 threads: one periodic 1ms RT thread to send data and one
thread to read the incoming messages. The read function looks like:

```
void readCan0Socket(void){
   int receivedBytes = 0;
   do
   {
      // set GPIO pin low
      receivedBytes = read(fd ,
                           &receiveCanFrame[recvBufferWritePosition],
                           sizeof(struct can_frame));
      // reset GPIO pin high

      if (receivedBytes != 0)
      {
         if (receivedBytes == sizeof(struct can_frame))
         {
            recvBufferWritePosition++;
            if (recvBufferWritePosition == CAN_MAX_RECEIVE_BUFFER_LENGTH)
            {
               recvBufferWritePosition = 0;
            }
         }
         receivedBytes = 0;
      }

   } while (1);
 }
```

The socket is configured in blocking mode, so the read function stays open
until a message arrived. The current implementation is working, but when
I measure the time between reading a message and the next waiting state of 
the read function (see set/reset GPIO comment) the time varies between 30 us
(the mean value) and > 200 us. A value greather than 200us means 
(CAN has a baud rate of 1000 kBit/s) that packages are not recognized while 
the read() handles the previous message. The read() function must be ready within 
134 us.

How can I accelerate my implementation? I tried to use two threads which are
separated with Mutexes (lock before the read() function and unlock after a 
message reception), but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: What does "see set/reset GPIO comment" mean ? Are you doing something more than what your code shows ? e.g. are you reading//writing a GPIO pin, which could incur significant latency ? Note that the socket also have a buffer, which will smooth over jitter  like you observe - you'll need to figure out if you're losing packets or read to slow *on average*.

Comment: You should drain the buffer every chance you get rather than just reading one frame and then moving on to do other stuff.

Comment: Yes, at the comment line I set / reset gpio pin. Toggling the gpio is fast enough I think. The average time of the read function is 30us. It is the spike values I'm concerned of.

Comment: I have never tried, but it should be possible to read many frames at a time by requesting `N*sizeof(struct can_frame)`, then doing your `read` non-blocking